# a problem in homological algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, homological-algebra

For $C$ is abelian group satisfied $pC=0$ with p is a prime number and $G$ is abelian group.

prove that

$Ext_{Z}(C,G)\cong Hom(C,G/pG)$

I thought about this in 2 hours but couldn't prove it!

Comment: maybe  regard $C=\mathbb{Z}_p$  @LorenoHeer

Comment: There is a nice proof of this statement in: S. Eilenberg  and S. MacLane,  On the groups H(t, n), II, Ann. of Math. vol. 60 (1954). Theorem 26.5 on Page 132.

Comment: @LorenoHeer Could you give pdf copy of that book? I looked for that book but ...

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/hC3U/1969702]_Samuel_Eilenberg_and_Saunders_MacLane_--_On_the_Groups_H(%EF%BF%BD_,_n),_II-_Methods_of_Computation.pdf